# Why $\{n\in\Bbb Z/m\ :\ nx=0 \}\cong \mathbb{Z} /d$, where $d=\gcd(m,n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here, I mean by $[\mathbb{Z}/m] [n] $ the set of elements $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}/m$, so that $na = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints.

The subgroup $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}[n]$ is the kernel of the homomorphism
$$
\mu_n\colon\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}
\qquad
\mu_n(x)=nx
$$
This kernel is cyclic, being a subgroup of a cyclic group.

The image of this homomorphism is
$$
n(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})=(n\mathbb{Z}+m\mathbb{Z})/m\mathbb{Z}
=d\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}
$$
which has $m/d$ elements. Therefore the kernel has
$$
m/(m/d)=d
$$
elements.

Comment: -1 Many claims but ZERO justifcations = *very* poor "answer".

Comment: @BillDubuque Do you think that giving hints on how to do homework needs full justifications? I don't think so. Besides, these are rather basic facts about cyclic groups.

Comment: Alas, your edit  (adding "Some hints" ) does not fix the pedagogical  gaps.

Comment: @BillDubuque This is not a lecture. And my aim certainly wasn't to go into every detail to begin with. Thanks for having pointed out the necessity of clarifying this is a series of hints. Bye.

Answer (score 1):

$na\equiv 0\bmod{m}$ means $m$ divides $na$, i.e., 
$$
\frac{m}{\gcd(m,n)} \text{ divides }a.
$$
Make your conclusions :)

Comment: Ok, then I get the order of $a$ divides $gcd(m,n)$, but I am lacking the final conclusion. I see that  $a \equiv 0, \ldots , d-1$ mod$ d$ satisfies this condition, but why are they the only ones?

Comment: You got that $a \in \mathbf{Z}$ satisfied the condition if and only if $a \in (m/\gcd(m,n))\mathbf{Z}$. Now consider that you go back to $\mathbf{Z}_m$. Then which are all and only the possible residue classes?

Comment: Sry, I don't see how to do it your way. So $a \in (m/gcd(m,n) \mathbb{Z} $, i.e.  $a = l* m/gcd(m,n) $ for some $l \in \mathbb{Z}$. I just see then for $l$, one can take $l = 0, \ldots , gcd(m,n)-1 $ until $ a \equiv 0 (m)$.

Comment: Right, in words, $a$ satisfies your condition iff it is a multiple of $k:= m/\gcd(m,n)$. But, in turn, $k$ is divisor of $m$. Hence, the only residue classes mod $m$ which works are the ones divisible by $k$.